# What are some problem solving tips when trying to attach an onclick() function to a button?

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I want my button to trigger a download of a PDF file when clicked. However, I am having trouble getting the button to fire the function when clicked. For now, I am just wanting the button to console.log "it works"

I have selected the correct element, and defined the type as "button", and am able to console.log the button. But when attaching the button.onclick()= function{ console.log("it works");}; it does not trigger the console.log in the console. I have also put the onclick function into a window.onload function.

```
 <div id="resume" class="resume">
    <button type="button" id="resume-button" class="resume-button">RESUME</button>
</div>
```

--JavaScript--

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.resume-button');

window.onload = function(){

button.onclick = function(){
    console.log("yay its working");
}; }
```

I am expecting the console to output "it works" when the button is clicked, but nothing happens when clicked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Comment: putting event binding inside the onload, but referencing the button outside of that method make no sense.

Answer (score 2):

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns an NodeList so that you need to access the button as the first element of this NodeList (`document.querySelectorAll('.resume-button')[0]`)

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll('.resume-button')[0];

button.onclick = function(){
  console.log("yay its working");
};
```

```html
<div id="resume" class="resume">
    <button type="button" id="resume-button" class="resume-button">RESUME</button>
</div>
```

Also note there is no need to wrap the onclick function assignment into `window.onload`

Comment: @epascarello Good point, thanks, I have removed the redundant wrapper